# Get the raw value of href and src attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Given an HTML element, I'd like to get the raw value of its src attribute using Javascript.

If the src value is relative path, element.src returns an absolute path.

For example:

1. //ssss.com ==> http(s)://ssss.com
2. blabla ==> http(s)://ssss.com/path/blabla

I know that it is possible to get the HTML code as string and to filter it, but this is not efficient.

I'm looking for efficient and clean way to extract the raw value of src/href attributes, given the HTML element with the attribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing object properties with attribute values. What's wrong with just using [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)?

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test');

console.log( element.href );
console.log( element.getAttribute('href') );
```

```html
<a href="test.html" id="test">Testy</a>
```

Notice that `element.href` is parsed by the browser, whereas `getAttribute()` returns the raw string that was specified in the DOM. You can also similarly use `getAttribute('src')` for `<img />` elements.

For completeness, this is the same behaviour that is demonstrated in jQuery. Most developers will use them synonymously, but they're actually subtly different.

For example:

```js
console.log( $('#test').prop('href') );
console.log( $('#test').attr('href') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="test.html" id="test">Testy</a>
```

Notice how `prop()` behaves in the same way as `element.href`, and `attr()` is identical to `getAttribute()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.getAttribute()`

```js
const src = document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("src")

console.log(src) // logs "/source"
```

```html
<img id="test" src="/source"/>
```